# Return values from table 1 Only when an value from table 2 = true

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL server 2012

I can come up with these two queries to get both pieces of what I need, but I can't figure out how to combine them and get a single table of results.

```
--Returns Max Value of instrument per day
Declare @StDate DateTime
Declare @EndDate DateTime
Set @STDate = '11/1/2012'
Set @EndDate = '12/1/2012'
Select dateadd(day,(datediff(day,0,TIMEandDATE)),0) as MyDate, MAX(Value) AS Max_Turb 
From Turbs where TagID = 3004
and TimeAndDate >= @StDate
and TimeAndDate < @EndDate
Group by dateadd(day,(datediff(day,0,TIMEandDATE)),0)
Order by dateadd(day,(datediff(day,0,TIMEandDATE)),0)

--returns when the process line status bit changes to On_Line
Declare @StDate DateTime
Declare @EndDate DateTime
Set @STDate = '11/1/2012'
Set @EndDate = '12/1/2012'
SELECT TIMEandDATE as MyDate, Value as On_Line
  FROM StatusBits
  Where TagID = 10003
  and Value = 1
  and TimeAndDate >= @StDate
and TimeAndDate < @EndDate
```

The TagID 10003 is not populated all day, it is only logged and time stamped when it changes state.

The TagID 3004 is logged all day long without regard to anything else. Because of this it will log values that are meaningless. The TagID 10003 bit indicates that the process is running, the values are valid and should be considered for the output. TagID 10003 bit is a global indication pertaining to many different processes and is not unique to this one value.

The result I am looking for needs to show the MAX value of TagID 3004 each day (From table Turbs), but ONLY using the values during the time between TagID 10003 becomes a '1' (online) until it becomes a '0' (OffLine). This could easily span many days or weeks.

Can anyone help me with this?

Update to reply:
Thanks for the reply - you have the right idea but it only returns a value for midnight each day which is what I have been seeing with my own attempts. I am beginning to think this database design is the real issue and that is going to drive me crazy if kept this way. 
TagID 3004 is logged every 5 minutes all day long.
TagID 10003 only gets logged when it changes value (and also at midnight each day). So if it doesn't change value for many hours or days I get no values from the second query. ANd even when it does, the timestamps for both would rarely match so its unlikely that a result would be found.

To demonstrate - with this query on the Online bit you can see how few entries exist per day for OnLine.

```
DECLARE @OnLine TABLE (RN int IDENTITY(1,1), TIMEandDATE datetime, VALUE float)
Declare @StartDT DateTime
Declare @EndDT DateTime
Set @StartDT = '11/1/2012'
Set @EndDT = '12/1/2012'

INSERT INTO @OnLine
               SELECT TOP 1 @StartDT, 
        VALUE FROM StatusBits 
        WHERE TagID = 10003 
        AND TIMEandDATE < @StartDT 
        ORDER BY TIMEandDATE DESC
INSERT INTO @OnLine
               SELECT TIMEandDATE, 
        VALUE FROM StatusBits 
        WHERE TagID = 10003
                AND TIMEandDATE >= @StartDT 
        AND TIMEandDATE < @EndDT
               ORDER BY TIMEandDATE
INSERT INTO @OnLine
               SELECT TOP 1 @ENDDT, 
        VALUE FROM StatusBits 
        WHERE TagID = 10003 
        AND TIMEandDATE < @EndDT 
        ORDER BY TIMEandDATE DESC
```

Returns the following:

```
record  Timestamp       Value
1   2012-11-01 00:00:00.000 0
2   2012-11-01 23:59:59.087 0
3   2012-11-02 23:11:44.450 1
4   2012-11-03 00:00:00.807 1
5   2012-11-03 13:47:26.113 0
6   2012-11-03 13:52:42.083 1
7   2012-11-03 14:24:54.287 0
8   2012-11-03 23:59:59.387 0
9   2012-11-04 23:34:16.257 1
10  2012-11-04 23:59:59.840 1
11  2012-11-05 15:31:07.133 1
12  2012-11-05 23:59:59.230 1
13  2012-11-06 07:47:37.477 0
14  2012-11-06 15:44:48.247 0
15  2012-11-06 23:59:59.013 0
16  2012-11-07 07:11:33.280 1
17  2012-11-08 00:00:00.537 1
```

I am trying to return results of tagID 3004 during the time between when TagID 10003 turns from a 0 until it turns to a 1.
I can't see how that is even possible to query for. 
Maybe using BETWEEN somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to select the values in your second table:

```
Declare @StDate DateTime = '11/1/2012'
Declare @EndDate DateTime = '12/1/2012'

;WITH
OnlineDates AS
(
    SELECT TIMEandDATE as MyDate
    FROM StatusBits
    Where TagID = 10003
        and Value = 1
        and TimeAndDate >= @StDate
        and TimeAndDate < @EndDate
)
Select dateadd(day,(datediff(day,0,TIMEandDATE)),0) as MyDate, MAX(Value) AS Max_Turb 
From Turbs T 
    INNER JOIN
        OnlineDates OD
    ON 
        t.TIMEandDATE BETWEEN 
        (
            SELECT TOP (1) X.TIMEandDATE
            FROM StatusBits X
            WHERE X.TagID = 10003
                AND X.Value = 0
                AND X.TIMEandDATE <= t.TIMEandDATE
            ORDER BY DESC

        )
        AND OD.MyDate
where TagID = 3004
Group by dateadd(day,(datediff(day,0,TIMEandDATE)),0)
Order by dateadd(day,(datediff(day,0,TIMEandDATE)),0)
```

Not sure, though, if what you want is to select max and min date from your second table and then filter by that.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: In an attempt to get what you are looking for, you want the TIMEandDATE BETWEEN X and Y. We already had Y. Then X will be the closest date with Value 0. Try the edited query above and let me know.

Comment: I edited the main question to reply, I dont see where to extend the forum thread beyond your answer.

Comment: Hey... that might just work. I'm  going to try this now. I see in the prior results the time portion of the time stamp is always 00:00:00.000 which means its either grabbing the value at midnight or its blanked out. If its midnight then the code is only seeing midnight and that's not what I need. So my question becomes is that the result of something in the Group By code? I would really like to see the actual time of the sample as well.